# federate office 365 without powershell

Tags: c#, office365, office365-apps

Is there a NON powershell way to set up federation with office365? 
an api to accomplish Set-MsolDomainAuthentication

office365apis

Comment: Why not call Powershell using `Process.Start`, or doesn't that work for you?

Comment: We're an idp and want to create an easier way for our customers to be provisioned and federated with us.  Already have the provisioning set up ( with the consent path and graph api )   and am looking to add the federation setup piece

Comment: Didn't answer my question: can't your software call powershell scripts?

Comment: Apologies :)  If i use powershell i have to get their administrators user name and password in order to complete the calls.   If there was a way to do this with consent then i would not have to prompt them.   Running the powershell under a webservice environment has it's own issues